# Pandas: equivalent to excel look up in python

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

I have a data frame such that

```
A   B
v1  2
v2  4
v3  6
v4  3
v5  5
v6  3
```

now I want to look up (col `B` value) for a value = v3 in column `A`. It shall give me an output 6. How shall I do that in python?

Answer (score 2):

You need create `Series` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
s = df.set_index('A')['B']
print (s)
A
v1    2
v2    4
v3    6
v4    3
v5    5
v6    3
Name: B, dtype: int64

print (s.loc['v3'])
#alternative:
#print (s['v3'])
6
```